# SQLServer 2016 linked server to iseries - catastrophic failure

Tags: linked-server

Environment: 
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
SQL Server 2016 Developer and SQL SERVER 2008 R2 installed.

Linked Server to iseries DB2 (MSDASQL on 64bit ODBC connection) works fine on SQLServer 2008 R2.

Linked SERVER to same DB2  from SQL Server 2016 instance does not work though the Linked SERVER catalog lists out the tables on iseries.

On running a select query using openquery, query comes out with the following error:

The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "test" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "test".

Query ouput tab shows all the column names in the table.

We have tried enabling Allow inprocess option on provider MSDASQL, dropping and recreating Linked Server etc.

Can any one help on this error please?